# Override a constructor class

Tags: java, constructor, overriding

Below is my code. I am not getting what is the mistake. Can anyone be able to guide.

```
class State {
    static String country;
    static String capital;

    State() // Constructor
    {
        country = "America's";
        capital = "Washington D.C";

    }

    static void display() {
        System.out.println(capital + " " + "is" + " " + country + " " + "capital.");

    }
}

class Place extends State // Method Overriding
{
    static void display() {
        System.out.println("Capital is Washington D.C.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        State st = new State();
        Place pl = new Place();
        st.display();
        pl.display();
        st = pl;

    }
}
```

While running it displays as "Error: Could not find or load main class State$Place"

> As the output needs: "Capital is Washington D.C." instead of (capital +
>   " " + "is" + " " + country + " " +"capital.")

Comment: what purpose of this ?? `st = pl;`

Comment: it work fine with me ....

Comment: displaying "Capital is Washington D.C." instead of (capital + " " + "is" + " " + country + " " +"capital.")

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run this code?

Comment: Also you can't override static methods. They are not polymorphic, just like final or private ones.

Comment: @YCF_L i am trying to run it using eclipse.

Comment: Wait, in your title you said you can't run this code, but now you said `displaying "Capital is Washington D.C." instead of (capital + " " + "is" + " " + country + " " +"capital.")`. So which is it? Are you able to run your code or not?

Comment: how are you running your program? using command line tools or using any IDE ?

Comment: Based on `State$Place` in your error it looks like you placed `Place` class inside `State` class. In that case you would get error about having static methods in non-static inner class, which would also prevent that class from compiling which would explain why you wouldn't be able to run it (since there is no `State$Place.class` file because of errors). But your code doesn't show that nested structure (you probably fixed it by now by correcting misplaced `{` `}`). Anyway in current form your question is unclear. Please [edit] it to clarify it.

Comment: @Pshemo he needs that.but it is not displaying

Comment: @bobmarti Notice that this question still *is* about "Error: Could not find or load main class State$Place". Comments about actual/expected results have nothing to do with it which is why I am asking OP to edit this question. IMO even better would be deletion of this question since it can't be corrected easily and asking separate one since that new problem has nothing to do with original one.

Comment: @Pshemo.. Will edit or will post a new one after sometime. After trying the possibilities visible from this post.

Comment: Changing visibility has nothing to do with error you described. `main` method can be executed even from `private static` nested classes. This error suggest that `State$Place.class` can't be found (probably because you recompiled your code and moved `Place` from inside of `State` to be separate top level class), or that it was compiled to throw such error when run because such code (having static method in non-static nested class) is invalid in Java. About your actual/expected output, it is hard to answer it because we don't know what makes you think that expected output should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
class State 
{
    static String country;
    static String capital;


    State()     //Constructor
    {
        country = "America's";
        capital = "Washington D.C";

    }

    static void display()
    {
        System.out.println(capital + " " + "is" + " " + country + " " +"capital." );

    }
}
```

---

**Main class**

```
class Place extends State // Inheritance 
    static void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Capital is Washington D.C.");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        State st = new State();
        st.display(); // to print sub class method 
        display(); // to print same class method 
        //st = pl; No idea of this point ..

    }
}
```

Comment: "*st.display(); // to print sub class method*" you probably meant sup (super) class, since `Place extends State` and `st` is of type `State`. In other words it is same as calling `State.display()` since `display` is static method.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Place` class needs to be defined as `public`.

Edit: The file also must be named `Place.java`

Comment: What makes you think so? Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @TomK And what makes you think that main method must be in public class?

Comment: `main` method doesn't need to be in public class. Also if top level class is not public it doesn't need to be in file with same name, so both aspects of your answer are simply wrong. I don't know who upvotes answers without testing them..

Comment: @Pshemo Making the Place class main compiled perfectly for me. Here was my output:

`
Washington D.C is America's capital.
Capital is Washington D.C.
`

Comment: "*Java only allows the main() method to be run in public classes*" no it doesn't. Counterexample: https://ideone.com/d3wSjj.

Comment: Is there a reason that this class has to be run in a non-public class? I'm not saying it's impossible for it to function without it, but it does work.

Comment: "Is there a reason that this class has to be run in a non-public class?" no but that is not a reason for problem described in question which is why I am saying your answer is simply wrong. It may contain good advice regarding good coding, but this can't sole OP problem (which from start is not really clear since we all can't reproduce it).

Comment: @Pshemo I was able to reproduce it. It gave me the exact same error that he described, but I was able to fix it on my end by making the Place class public.

Comment: I also tested OP code as it is and it compiled/run fine, so it can't be problem with visibility. I don't know how you ware able to get same error but changing visibility wasn't reason you solved it.