# Error: Could not find or load main class State$Place

Tags: java

Below is my set of code and the file name is `State.java`

```
class State 
{
    static String country;
    static String capital;


    State()     //Constructor
    {
        country = "America's";
        capital = "Washington D.C";

    }

    static void display()
    {
        System.out.println(capital + " " + "is" + " " + country + " " +"capital." );

        }
     }

    class Place extends State
    {
        static void display()
    {
            System.out.println("Capital is Washington D.C.");
        }


            public static void main(String[] args)
            {

                State st = new State();           
                Place pl = new Place();
                st.display();
                pl.display();
                st = pl;

            }

    }
```

`Error: Could not find or load main class State$Place` is getting displayed when i am trying to run it.

My main intention is to display **`Capital is Washington D.C.`** instead of `capital + " " + "is" + " " + country + " " +"capital."`. I have used a constructor as well.

I am using eclipse IDE to execute my program.

Comment: There's no need to put the main method into an inner class and AFAIK that's not even allowed.

Comment: Put your main method in its own class separate from the models. That gives you better code organization

Comment: Also, please learn more  about `static` variables/methods and see why your State class in not quite correct

Comment: @cricket_007...yeah i modified the location of main class. Now, it's displaying both the messages. But i want to display only Capital is Washington D.C.

Comment: @cricket_007...Please check my reply to Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made a quick test and contrary to my comment it seems that static inner classes are allowed to contain a main method. The problem with your code, however, is that *only* static inner classes are allowed to contain static methods (see [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)). Since `Place` is not a static inner class it cannot have a main method which is required to be static.

Besides that you should probably move your main method to the outer class or another class altogether (see cricket's comment as well).

Comment: @Thomas...i did the same as you said. Now it working. But displaying both the messages. I need to display only one and that is Capital is Washington D.C.

Comment: @Arvind Just remove `st.display();` from main method.

Comment: @Thomas...But what about method overriding which i am trying to do in class Place extends State.

Comment: @Arvind you can't override static methods, just hide them. I guess you want to remove the `static` keyword from `display()`.

Comment: Please note that OP didn't post any nested classes in this question. Java is not python, here scope (nesting) is done by `{` `}` not by tabulators and if we apply proper indentation we will see two top-level classes so there is none `State$Place` in posted example.

Comment: BTW this question is almost exact duplicate of OP previous one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419185/override-a-constructor-class. I already voted to close that other question as off-topic because it doesn't allow us to reproduce the problem, so I can't dupe-hammer it as duplicate of this one. Could you cast your dupe vote there (if you agree that they are duplicates)?

Comment: @Pshemo yeah, you're right. I'll close the question. And you're right about the nesting, I missed that closing brace due to the intendation - and that `State$Place` made me think the rest was just poor formatting.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, in OP *real* code at some `Place` most likely was inside `State` class which explains this error, but currently situation changed and we can't reproduce such error. Maybe OP needs to clear his project and/or change configuration used to runs his code. Hard to tell.